# Can we add other contents after closing a direct speech's quotation with a full stop?

Tags: reported-speech

When we write direct speech sentences with a question mark ending, we can write something after. For example, <‘Can I come in?’ *he asked*.> Then, can we write something after when we end the direct speeches with a full stop? For example, <'I didn't expect to win.' I said.>

Comment: *"I've always wanted to be called Mrs." she said.*

Comment: @StuartF I believe that still needs a comma:  *“… to be called Mrs.,” she said.*

Answer (score 2):

When the punctuation is a question mark, your usage is correct. However, you do not use a fullstop, rather, you simply place a comma as such "I didn't expect to win", he said.

Check this helpful article if you need more:

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-quotation-marks

Hope this helps :)